How can I find the direct flight routes, the one transfer routes and the two transfer routes from a specific destination? Using OpenFlight data
I have a file, called routes from https://openflights.org/data.php with the following columns:
Airline 2-letter (IATA) or 3-letter (ICAO) code of the airline.
Airline ID  Unique OpenFlights identifier for airline (see Airline).
Source airport  3-letter (IATA) or 4-letter (ICAO) code of the source airport.
Source airport ID   Unique OpenFlights identifier for source airport (see Airport)
Destination airport 3-letter (IATA) or 4-letter (ICAO) code of the destination airport.
Destination airport ID  Unique OpenFlights identifier for destination airport (see Airport)
Codeshare   "Y" if this flight is a codeshare (that is, not operated by Airline, but another carrier), empty otherwise.
Stops   Number of stops on this flight ("0" for direct)
Equipment   3-letter codes for plane type(s) generally used on this flight, separated by spaces

.
First, I want to find those routes that are sourced from the destinations of my direct flights from a specific airport (LEX for example). An then do the same for the two transfer routes.
I used pandas to create dataframes from the csv.
# Get the list of all destination airports from LEX
lex_destinations = lex_routes['dest'].unique()

# Select routes from those destination airports
one_transfer_routes = routes[routes['source'].isin(lex_destinations)]

# Remove routes that come back to LEX (or revisit any airport twice)
one_transfer_routes = one_transfer_routes[~one_transfer_routes['dest'].isin(['LEX'])]

#Join with the airports to have the lat, lon to plot them using folium
one_transfer_routes_1 = pd.merge(one_transfer_routes, airports, 
                      left_on='dest_id', 
                      right_on='id', 
                      how='left', 
                      suffixes=['_source','_dest'])

# Get the list of all destinations from LEX's first connections
first_transfer_destinations = one_transfer_routes['dest'].unique()

# Get routes from those destinations to find second transfer connections
two_transfer_routes = routes[routes['source'].isin(first_transfer_destinations)]

# Again, filter out any routes that come back to LEX or revisit any airport twice
two_transfer_routes = two_transfer_routes[~two_transfer_routes['dest'].isin(['LEX'])]

two_transfer_routes = pd.merge(two_transfer_routes, airports, 
                      left_on='dest_id', 
                      right_on='id', 
                      how='left', 
                      suffixes=['_source','_dest'])

